# Expansion of cube of four terms

Tags: linear-algebra, cubics

How do I get to know the pattern that appears when we open the cube of four terms ?

For example, how do I get to know this pattern?

> $(a+b+c+d)^3=\sum a^3 $ +6 $\sum abc$ + 3$\sum b a^2$

Comment: What is $\sum a^3$ ?

Comment: That was a mistake on my part. Edited it

Comment: You can consider $((a+b)+(c+d))^3$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your expansion is missing lots of terms. Take some time to work it out carefully. Edit the question to show your better result. You can partly check your answer by seeing if it's right when all four variables have value $1$. Then ask about the pattern if you don't see it.

Comment: This expansion was given in a reference book and i couldn't figure out the pattern.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA isn't there a shorter method?

Comment: @Alottadoubts This does not look like an expansion using any standard notation. I suggest you check the book again. What are the sums over for example?

Comment: @Johanna the book asks for the sum of cube of roots of an equation of degree 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $(a+b+c+d)^3$ we know that all terms will exactly have a degree $3$. Now all distinct types of terms possible are $\sum_{cyc}a^3, \sum_{cyc}a^2b, \sum_{cyc}abc$. Coefficients can be evaluated using counting principles.

For example, coefficient of $a^3$ will be $\binom{3}{3}$, that of $a^2b$ will be $\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}$, and that of $abc$ will be $\binom{3}{1} \binom{2}{1} \binom{1}{1}$

To conclude, you can write:

$$(a+b+c+d)^3 = \binom{3}{3}\sum_{cyc}a^3+ \binom{3}{2} \binom{1}{1}\sum_{cyc}a^2b+ \binom{3}{1} \binom{2}{1} \binom{1}{1}\sum_{cyc}abc$$

Comment: Could you explain why you took (3C2)(1C1) with a²b and (3C1)(2C1)(1C1) with abc

Comment: @Alottadoubts $(a+b+c+d)^3$ had $3$ factors. For getting $a^2b$ we need to choose two factors from where $a$ has to be taken to form $a^2$ so we get to choose 2 from 3, and one factor from where $b$ has to be taken, so we choose one the 1 factor left. Similarly for abc, we first choose $a$ from one factor out of the three, two factors left. We choose now 1 factor out of the 2 left from which we take b and lastly c is chosen from the last remaining factor.